# IONIC 2, loop through object

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I have this object:

```
 {"": "Select job type", F: "Full-time", P: "Part-time", C: "Contract", T: "Temporary}
```

I want to be able to loop through it and get the key and value. I plan to write a function that looks like

```
getJobType(letter){
       let jobType = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jobType'))

        //if my letter matches the key in the object then i want to return the value

    }
```

I have tried :

```
 Object.keys(JSON.parse(jobType)).forEach(key=> {
   console.log(jobType[key])  ;     
   });
```

and

```
  jobType.forEach( (value, key, index) => {
    console.log("This is the value", value)
    console.log("from the key", key)
})
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing " at the end of "Temporary". Below code works for iteration. You can also use filter method to filter out the values.

```
var jobTypes = {"": "Select job type", F: "Full-time", P: "Part-time", C: "Contract", T: "Temporary"};

Object.keys(jobTypes).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(jobTypes[key])
});
```